# Render 2500 geoJSON polygons onto a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openstreetmap, leaflet

I've been searching but cannot seem to find a solution.

I have a GeoJSON file which is 170mb in size. It contains about 2500 polygons. Somehow I need to render it to a leaflet map. Evidently at that size I have no chance.

What will the easiest way to render this data? Am I able to create a complete transparent png which can simply be rendered over the world map. The huge size is due to the complexity and the number of polygons. At this point I don't need it to be interactive.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to create your own map tiles based on that data. There are a couple of ways of achieving this but my suggestion is that you use [TileMill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/). It's free and very easy to use. So, basically you would:

- Use TileMill and specify your GeoJSON file as the data-source
- Configure how the map should be displayed (like the color of the polygons) with a special CSS-like language inside TileMill
- Generate the tiles
- Load a new TileLayer in your Leaflet map that references your files

I've actually written a tutorial some time ago that uses a .shp instead of a GeoJson, but should be similar enough:

http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/03/custom-map-tiles-part-2-tilemill.html

Comment: these blog posts have some invaluable info

Comment: TileMill is now at https://github.com/tilemill-project/tilemill and is still at v0.10 - the successor is Mapbox Studio - see https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/

Answer (score 8):

There is also [geojson-vt](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt), which apparently [can to the tiling serverless on-the-fly](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/introducing-geojson-vt/) - after a bit of loading time.

[image: demo gif from GitHub]

Answer (score 7):

I cannot argue with psousa's recommendation. For a straightforward presentation, TileMill is a great idea.

However, if you want to overlay your polygons onto another map, I reckon the only way is by using Mike Bostock's TopoJSON and D3.

The main TopoJSON page:
https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki

An example at the scale you are talking about:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4206573

You'll have to shop around Mike's excellent examples on github to see how to combine leaflet with a D3 overlay.

I'm currently doing this successfully with hundreds of complex polygons. Haven't had the need to break into the thousands ... yet.

Comment: TopoJSON excels when you have contiguous polygons, like states/cities/countries, which I'm not sure is the case here.

Comment: "only way" is a bold claim.

Comment: @EricHartford i agree. Don't know if Mapbox has a solution for this

Comment: @arcsum they do. I added a pointer to it [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41934415/512111).

Answer (score 3):

Just another humble suggestion.
I had successfully done loading 10000+ polygons and querying attributes by rolling out my own Geoserver and PostgreSQL DB + PostGIS instance and producing a WMS (not WFS), as you can see in the image.

[image: 10000+ polygons]

But it is not straightforward to implement, especially if the geojson data is the original (and only) data

In that regard I would second psousa's answer to use TileMill.