# Showing tile images by leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, image, leaflet

i have to show tiles images in my web pages. i found one article here http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/showing-zoomify-images-with-leaflet.html

which used leaflet.js to show tile images. it is good but code was not very clear to me.

### this below line is not clear to me

```
L.tileLayer.zoomify('http://thematicmapping.org/playground/zoomify/books/', {
    width: 5472,
    height: 3648,
    tolerance: 0.8,
    attribution: 'Photo: Bjørn Sandvik'
}).addTo(map);
```

this is just a url `http://thematicmapping.org/playground/zoomify/books/` which i open and found there are some other folders `TileGroup0 and TileGroup1`

but books folder has no images. so my question is from where the leaflet.js is loading tile images ?

if we need to provide zoom/pan facility then do i need to store zoom related images in separate folder ? if yes then guide me where to store zoom images and how to inform leaflet.js to load zoom related images from a specific folder when user click on zoom-in and out related button.

what this property does `attribution: 'some text'` ?

what this line is doing `setView(new L.LatLng(0,0), 0);` why all zero passed as parameter value for `setView & LatLng function`.

Comment: http://openseadragon.github.io/

Comment: try openlayer lib for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744208/how-to-fix-map-using-leaflet-run-is-very-slow-on-firefox-browser
http://jsfiddle.net/TienKenji/VnhbA/9/
http://jsfiddle.net/VnhbA/12/